# Change event not being triggered on text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, jquery-events

I'm trying to bind a function to 'change' event but it isn't working. So far I've tried using 4 methods.

1.

```
$('#search').on('change', function(){ console.log('a') })
```

2. 

```
$('#search').change(function(){ console.log('a') })
```

3. 

```
$(document).on('change', '#search', function(){ console.log('a') })
```

4. 

```
document.getElementById('search').onchange = function(){ console.log('a') }
```

None of them are working. I tried adding them from console (Chrome's dev tool).

[Here](http://node.thewhitefang.xyz:3000) is the page I am trying to make it work on. Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Please provide your sample in a [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: There is no code on your page that addresses the element with an id of `search` - looks like you just forgot to include the code.

Comment: Well actually I removed the code and was trying to make it work in console first. And hence i gave the link to the page. But  your suggestion to use 'input' event worked. Thanks. Can you make it into a short answer so I can mark it as solved to avoid open questions clutter. Thanks again. :)

Comment: ran the code on console on your page, worked fine. I guess you are expecting cange to do something it is not meant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the `input` event, the `change` event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value. You can/should use the `input` event instead of `change`. It fires on every keystroke and even if you just paste something from the clipboard:

```js
document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener('input', e => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
})
```